# Hex number literal in MySQL stored function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, hex

I want to use hexadecimal literals in the code of a MySQL function that does operations with bit masks on BIGINTs.

According to the [MySQL 5.6 manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/hexadecimal-literals.html), I can use hexadecimal literals for integer values.
This works from an SQL statement in MySQL 5.6:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(0x0055aa55aa55aaff AS UNSIGNED);
+--------------------------------------+
| CAST(0x0055aa55aa55aaff AS UNSIGNED) |
+--------------------------------------+
|                    24112657927088895 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I'm now trying to use the same syntax from a stored function, on the same MySQL:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS _test_hex_literal;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION _test_hex_literal()
    RETURN BIGINT UNSIGNED
    DETERMINISTIC
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(0x0055aa55aa55aaff AS UNSIGNED);
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
SELECT _test_hex_literal();
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS _test_hex_literal;
```

But MySQL 5.6 is rejecting my code:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURN BIGINT UNSIGNED
    DETERMINISTIC
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(0x0055' at line 2
```

**Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug in MySQL?**

If this is a MySQL bug, is there a **workaround** to use hexadecimal constants in the source code of my function?

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo: I wrote `RETURN` instead of `RETURNS` in the function signature.

Here is the fixed code:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS _test_hex_literal;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION _test_hex_literal()
    RETURNS BIGINT UNSIGNED
    DETERMINISTIC
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(0x0055aa55aa55aaff AS UNSIGNED);
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
SELECT _test_hex_literal();
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS _test_hex_literal;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error complaints about `RETURN`, not hexadecimal literals:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '**RETURN** BIGINT UNSIGNED
>       DETERMINISTIC
>       NO SQL BEGIN
>       RETURN CAST(0x0055'

Here's [the syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html):

```
CREATE
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    FUNCTION sp_name ([func_parameter[,...]])
    RETURNS type
          ^
    [characteristic ...] routine_body
```